# Creating a table with latex

Tags: latex

I'm wondering how can I create a kind of table attached here with latex?
**table in latex**

[image]

Comment: http://texblog.org/2012/12/21/multi-column-and-multi-row-cells-in-latex-tables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [page](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/) to help you design tables in latex.

The example that you're asking can be done with the code below:

```
%Add this package to your preamble
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{A}                                                                         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}C\\ D\end{tabular}}        & B                  \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}H\\ I\end{tabular}     & G & \multirow{2}{*}{F} & \multirow{3}{*}{E} \\ \cline{1-2}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}L\\ M\\ N\end{tabular} & K &                    &                    \\ \cline{1-3}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Q\\ R\end{tabular}     & P & O                  &                    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Thank you in advance for your answer, but actually because I am using it in persiantext format, when I run the code you've suggested, the table becomes completely symmetric in comparison with the one I asked. Do you know how can I fix it?